# Download one specific Outlook attachment from an email with multiple attachments

Tags: python-3.x, outlook, email-attachments

Working on a Python 3 win32com.client script that only searches for emails from a specific sender and downloads 1 out of multiple attachments.

The issue I have is that in the instances where an email has two attachments, it tries to download and rename both, which overwrites the first file that I want with the second attachment.

The file attachment has a specific filename but there is another attachment with a similar name.

So far I have:

```
import win32com.client
import os

mydesktop = os.path.expanduser('~') + '/Desktop/'
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

# Select main Inbox
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items

sender = 'mysender@domain'
MyDailyfolder = mydesktop + 'My Daily Data/'

try:
    for message in messages:
        msg_date = message.SentOn.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        try:
            s = message.sender
            s = str(s)
            if s == sender:
                for att in message.Attachments:
                    if "Dashboard2_dashboard2" in att.FileName:  #<---This doesn't work.
                        outfile_name2 = 'MycustomName' + msg_date + '.csv'

                    outfile_path2 = MyDailyfolder + outfile_name2
                    if not os.path.exists(MyDailyfolder): os.makedirs(MyDailyfolder)
                    # save file 
                    att.SaveASFile(outfile_path2)
                    print('Saved file:', outfile_name2)
        except:
            x=1
except:
    x=1
```

The result downloads all of the attached files in an email to a new folder on my desktop but it overwrites each copy.  I'm trying to select only the attachment that contains "Dashboard2dashboard2" on it.  I think I have to use "for part in msg.walk():" but have never used that command before.  Any ideas?

Comment: You can use the `pass` keyword, instead of writing `x=1`

Comment: "pass" sounds more intuitive, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ah the issue is a typo in my filename search.  An extra underscore.  Added an extra print in each step to make sure each part is valid.

```
sender = 'mysender@domain'
MyDailyfolder = mydesktop + 'My Daily Data/'

try:
    for message in messages:
        msg_date = message.SentOn.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        try:
            s = message.sender
            s = str(s)
            if s == sender:
                print('Sender:' , message.sender)
                for att in message.Attachments:
                    if "dashboard_2.csv" in att.FileName:
                        outfile_name = msg_date + att.FileName
                        print ('Match search confirmed')

                    # Backup test, print filename and watch spelling
                    print (att.FileName)

                    # Create a folder and copy/paste attachment there
                    outfile_path = MyDailyfolder + outfile_name
                    if not os.path.exists(MyDailyfolder): os.makedirs(MyDailyfolder)

                    # save file 
                    att.SaveASFile(outfile_path)
        except:
            pass
except:
    pass
```